# Setting local environment from the AWS parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a better approach to setup the environment, say via aws cli or even aws-vault to setup the environment from the parameter store?

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -f .env
then
    echo .env already exists. Stopping.
    exit
fi

ssm() {
    echo $(aws ssm get-parameters --names $1 --with-decryption --query Parameters[0].Value --output text)
}

cat << EOF > .env
SLACK_HOOK=$(ssm SlackAlertHook)
EOF
```

Comment: In general, no. If the code is running on AWS ECS or EKS, then yes.

Comment: What annoys me is the "None" if the parameter is not found.

Comment: It would be fairly trivial to pipe that `ssm` command to `awk` or `sed` or something to strip out `None` values if you need to. If you want specific help with that, that should be detailed in the question.